# reading text file with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to select the first two columns in a text file with the following structure:

```
# Log file
# time, ft, t, d, wx, wy
2.00000000,1.82266415,205082.33545232,501.88487172,-1.16541985,-0.97270584
3.00000000,1.82266415,205082.33545232,752.83193437,-1.16553201,-0.97285083
4.00000000,1.82266415,205082.33545232,1003.78266552,-1.16564190,-0.97299267
5.00000000,1.82266415,205082.33545232,1254.73750199,-1.16574956,-0.97313135
```

I would like to graph and integrate the second column over the first column,
so first getting the first and second column in arrays or lists like x = [2.00, 3,00,...]
and y = [1.82266, 1.822664,...]

The code I use is as follows:

```
data = pd.read_csv('perflog.txt', sep=" ", header=None, skiprows = 2)

data.columns = ["time", "ft", "t", "d", "wx", "wy"]
```

However, this raised the following: ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 6 elements.

I am using skiprows to ignore the first two lines, anyone knows how I would obtain the arrays/list as required?

Comment: Clearly `sep=" "` makes no sense.

Comment: So when I remove this, how would I go about obtaining the arrays as required?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('perflog.txt', sep=",", header=None, skiprows=2)
data.columns = ["time", "ft", "t", "d", "wx", "wy"]

print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks! this seems to show the dataframe as a whole. How would I obtain say the first and second column? I tried print(data[0]) but this doesnt give the first column, but a KeyError:0

Comment: I got it, I use print (data["time"])

Comment: or data.time and data.ft